# Awk: print the cumulative sum next to the original value

Tags: awk

The input text file contains 4 fields which are separated by | as seen here:

```
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900
```

The intent of the following script is to print the cumulative sum of $4 in $5.  I.e.on each row, next to the original value of $4, print the sum of all above values.

As you can see in the actual output below, the cumulative sum is achieved, but something in my script is causing each line of my input file to print beneath each line of my expected output.

```
    $ awk -F '|' '{total += $4; print $0"|",total}1' infile.txt
```

Expected output:

```
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
```

Actual Output:

```
Name|Payment|Date|-900| -900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900| 0
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900| -900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900| 0
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900| -900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900| 0
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900| -900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900| 0
Name|Invoice|Date|900
Name|Payment|Date|-900| -900
Name|Payment|Date|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900| 0
Name|Invoice|Date|900
```

Comment: your `1` at the end means print the current record, that's why you see dups.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'|' '{___+=$NF; print $0 FS ___}' file

Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
Name|Payment|Date|-900|-900
Name|Invoice|Date|900|0
```

Comment: You might want to pick another variable name so this post is visible and the code can be copy/pasted anywhere. I wish I was kidding :-). See https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2018/05/22/proud-mom-orders-summa-cum-laude-cake-online-publix-censors-it-to-summa-laude/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.646532670edd.